# How to set position or linear movement for any object and and add objects with free fall?

Tags: html, python-3.x, drake

I would like to simulate system like "vibrating table" with linear displacement.

I studied several examples from tutorials:

1. According to tutorial "Authoring a Multibody Simulation" I was able to get a simulation of a given number of objects free falling onto a table from different heights like this:

```
table_sdf = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sdf version="1.7">
  <model name="table_top">
    <link name="table_link">
      <visual name="visual">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.55 1.1 0.05</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
         <diffuse>0.9 0.8 0.7 1.0</diffuse>
        </material>
      </visual>
      <collision name="collision">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.55 1.1 0.05</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <frame name="table_center">
      <pose relative_to="table_link">0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </frame>
  </model>
</sdf>
"""
```

```
def create_scene(sim_time_step):

    builder = DiagramBuilder()
    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(
        builder, time_step=sim_time_step)
    parser = Parser(plant)

    # Loading models
    parser.SetAutoRenaming(True)
    parser.AddModelsFromString(table_sdf, "sdf")

    # Adding some objects in scene
    num_of_parts = 3
    objects_instance = []
    for i in range(num_of_parts):
        objects_instance.append(parser.AddModels(url="package://drake/manipulation/models/ycb/sdf/005_tomato_soup_can.sdf")[0])

    table_frame = plant.GetFrameByName("table_center")
    plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), table_frame)

    # Finalize the plant after loading the scene.
    plant.Finalize()

    # We use the default context to calculate the transformation of the table
    # in world frame but this is NOT the context the Diagram consumes.
    plant_context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()

    # Define the orientaion of added objects
    objects = []
    X_TablePart = []
    X_WorldPart = []
    for i in range(num_of_parts):
        objects.append(plant.GetBodyByName("base_link_soup", model_instance=objects_instance[i]))
        X_WorldTable = table_frame.CalcPoseInWorld(plant_context)
        X_TablePart.append(RigidTransform(
            RollPitchYaw(np.asarray([random.uniform(0,180), random.uniform(0,180), random.uniform(0,180)]) * np.pi / 180),
            p=[random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2), random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2), 0.3+random.uniform(-0.05, 0.05)]))
        X_WorldPart.append(X_WorldTable.multiply(X_TablePart[i]))
        plant.SetDefaultFreeBodyPose(objects[i], X_WorldPart[i])

    # Add visualization to see the geometries.
    AddDefaultVisualization(builder=builder, meshcat=meshcat)
    diagram = builder.Build()

    return diagram


def initialize_simulation(diagram):
    simulator = Simulator(diagram)
    simulator.Initialize()
    simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.)
    return simulator

def run_simulation(sim_time_step, sim_time):
    diagram = create_scene(sim_time_step)
    simulator = initialize_simulation(diagram)

    meshcat.StartRecording()
    simulator.AdvanceTo(sim_time)
    meshcat.PublishRecording()

meshcat = StartMeshcat()
# Run the simulation with a small time step. Try gradually increasing it!
run_simulation(sim_time_step=0.0001, sim_time=2)
```

2. According to first part of "03 - Basic Pick and Place => pick" I was able to get a simulation of periodic movement of the table in a linear direction

```
def MakeGripperFrames(X_WG):
    Initial_position = RigidTransform([0., 0., 0.])
    Final_position = RigidTransform([0.5, 0., 0.])

    X_WG["one"] = Initial_position
    X_WG["two"] = Final_position
    X_WG["three"] = Initial_position
    X_WG["four"] = Final_position
    X_WG["five"] = Initial_position


    # Now let's set the timing
    times = {"zero": 0}
    times["one"] = times["zero"] + 2 * 2
    times["two"] = times["zero"] + 2 * 3
    times["three"] = times["zero"] + 2 * 4
    times["four"] = times["zero"] + 2 * 5
    times["five"] = times["zero"] + 2 * 6

    return X_WG, times


def MakeGripperPoseTrajectory(X_G, times):
    """
    Constructs a gripper position trajectory from the plan "sketch".
    """
    sample_times = []
    poses = []
    for name in [
        "zero",
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",
        "five",
    ]:
        sample_times.append(times[name])  # вывести их через принт
        poses.append(X_G[name])

    return PiecewisePose.MakeLinear(sample_times, poses)


class GripperTrajectoriesToPosition(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self, plant, traj_p_G, traj_R_G):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self.plant = plant
        self.plant_context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()
        self.table_body = plant.GetBodyByName("table_link")
        self.traj_p_G = traj_p_G
        self.traj_R_G = traj_R_G
        self.W = plant.world_frame()

        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "position", plant.num_positions(), self.CalcPositionOutput
        )

    def CalcPositionOutput(self, context, output):
        t = context.get_time()
        X_G = RigidTransform(
            Quaternion(self.traj_R_G.value(t)), self.traj_p_G.value(t)
        )
        self.plant.SetFreeBodyPose(self.plant_context, self.table_body, X_G)
        output.SetFromVector(self.plant.GetPositions(self.plant_context))


def visualize_pick_and_place_trajectory(traj_p_G, traj_R_G):
    builder = DiagramBuilder()

    # Note: Don't use AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph because we are only using
    # MultibodyPlant for parsing, then wiring directly to SceneGraph.
    scene_graph = builder.AddSystem(SceneGraph())
    plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.0001)
    plant.RegisterAsSourceForSceneGraph(scene_graph)
    parser = Parser(plant, scene_graph)
    object_1 = parser.AddModelsFromString(table_sdf, "sdf")[0]

    plant.Finalize()

    to_pose = builder.AddSystem(MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose(plant))
    builder.Connect(
        to_pose.get_output_port(),
        scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(plant.get_source_id()),
    )

    traj_to_position = builder.AddSystem(
        GripperTrajectoriesToPosition(
            plant, traj_p_G, traj_R_G
        )
    )
    builder.Connect(
        traj_to_position.get_output_port(), to_pose.get_input_port()
    )

    MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
    diagram = builder.Build()

    simulator = Simulator(diagram)
    simulator.Initialize()
    simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(2.)
    meshcat.StartRecording(set_visualizations_while_recording=False)
    simulator.AdvanceTo(traj_p_G.end_time())
    meshcat.PublishRecording()
```

```
# Start the visualizer.
meshcat = StartMeshcat()
X_G = {
    "zero": RigidTransform([0, 0, 0.])
}

X_G, times = MakeGripperFrames(X_G)
traj_X_G = MakeGripperPoseTrajectory(X_G, times)
traj_p_G = traj_X_G.get_position_trajectory()   
traj_R_G = traj_X_G.get_orientation_trajectory()
visualize_pick_and_place_trajectory(traj_p_G, traj_R_G)
```

And I don't understand how to combine these two solutions together.

If it's possible, could you get some advices about consctruct this system in Drake?
I tried to add some block of codes in first solution and vice versa - it didn't work.

My full code here in two notebooks (DeepNote):[DeepNote-project](https://deepnote.com/workspace/evgen1237-da02cefd-30d6-4b83-a00f-7da64b94136c/project/Mycodesandnotes-13705a01-6f73-4fb4-81b2-04910240b628/notebook/Falling%20objects-1ede3317c1144776900b4e21390ea534)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to add an object that will able to fall down due to gravity from some position if I use Multibody plant class (in point 2. above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Russ Tedrake, thank you for your answers and I solved my task with your help and added some ideas else. I would like to write here these ideas and I hope this helps someone else in the future. Perhaps I used some tools differently than how it was originally intended in Drake, I will be glad to know how to do it correctly!

First, my goal was to get a model containing:

- mechanism with actuated joints the desired position of which could vary over time. (for example: 0 deg in 1 sec, 45 deg in 2 sec, 0 deg in 3 sec and ...)
- floating body, which falling down from required position.

As a mechanism with several degrees of freedom, I took a double pendulum (DP), and as a free object, a can of soup from YCB-library.

DP:

```
dp_sdf = """<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <model name='double_pendulum_with_base'>
    <link name='base'>
      <inertial>
        <mass>100</mass>
      </inertial>
      <visual name='vis_plate_on_ground'>
        <pose>0 0 0.01 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.8</radius>
            <length>0.02</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <visual name='vis_pole'>
        <pose>-0.275 0 1.1 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.2 0.2 2.2</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision name='col_plate_on_ground'>
        <pose>0 0 0.01 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.8</radius>
            <length>0.02</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <collision name='col_pole'>
        <pose>-0.275 0 1.1 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.2 0.2 2.2</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <!-- upper link, length 1, angle -90 degrees -->
    <link name='upper_link'>
      <pose>0 0 2.1 0 0 0</pose>
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>30.0</mass>
      </inertial>
      <visual name='vis_upper_joint'>
        <pose>-0.05 0 0 0 1.5708 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.1</radius>
            <length>0.3</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <visual name='vis_lower_joint'>
        <pose>0 0 1.0 0 1.5708 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.1</radius>
            <length>0.2</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <visual name='vis_cylinder'>
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.1</radius>
            <length>0.9</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision name='col_upper_joint'>
        <pose>-0.05 0 0 0 1.5708 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.1</radius>
            <length>0.3</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <collision name='col_lower_joint'>
        <pose>0 0 1.0 0 1.5708 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.1</radius>
            <length>0.2</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <collision name='col_cylinder'>
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.1</radius>
            <length>0.9</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <!-- lower link, length 1, angle ~-120 degrees more -->
    <link name='lower_link'>
      <pose>0.25 0.0 3.1 0 0 0</pose>
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>30.0</mass>
      </inertial>
      <visual name='vis_lower_joint'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 1.5708 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.08</radius>
            <length>0.3</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <visual name='vis_cylinder'>
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.1</radius>
            <length>0.9</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision name='col_lower_joint'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 1.5708 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.08</radius>
            <length>0.3</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <collision name='col_cylinder'>
        <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>0.1</radius>
            <length>0.9</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <!-- pin joint for upper link, at origin of upper link -->
    <joint name='upper_joint' type='revolute'>
      <parent>base</parent>
      <child>upper_link</child>
      <axis>
        <xyz>1.0 0 0</xyz>
        <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
        <limit>
          <effort>0.0</effort>
        </limit>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <!-- pin joint for lower link, at origin of child link -->
    <joint name='lower_joint' type='revolute'>
      <parent>upper_link</parent>
      <child>lower_link</child>
      <axis>
        <xyz>1.0 0 0</xyz>
        <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
        <limit>
          <effort>0.0</effort>
        </limit>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <frame name="dp_base">
      <pose relative_to="base">0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    </frame>
  </model>
</sdf>
"""
```

So,

1. For convenience, let's define a few variables:

```
sim_step = 0.0001 # Simulation step
sim_time = 10 # Simulation time
num_of_actuated_joints = 2 # Number of actuated joints
num_of_objects = 2 # Number of free objects
```

2. Set the required joint positions:

```
def MakeTrajectory(joint_name):
 # There are only two desired positions for every joints becauce I'd like to get periodic motion
    if joint_name == "lower_joint":
        first_pos = np.array([0])    # This corresponds to 0 deg
        second_pos = np.array([0.7]) # This corresponds to ~40 deg (given in radians)
    elif joint_name == "upper_joint":
        first_pos = np.array([0])
        second_pos = np.array([1.4])
    else:
        first_pos = np.array([0])
        second_pos = np.array([0])

    times = np.array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]) # Timestamps for positions

    # Set the desired positions/trajectory through special class by defining two first points of trajectory
    traj_command = PiecewisePolynomial.FirstOrderHold(
        [times[0], times[1]],
        np.hstack([[first_pos], [first_pos]]),
    )
    # Add additional positions
    traj_command.AppendFirstOrderSegment(times[2], second_pos)
    traj_command.AppendFirstOrderSegment(times[3], first_pos)
    traj_command.AppendFirstOrderSegment(times[4], second_pos)
    traj_command.AppendFirstOrderSegment(times[5], first_pos)

    return traj_command
    
# Getting desired trajectories for all of two joints of DP
traj_JT1_command = MakeTrajectory(joint_name="lower_joint")
traj_JT2_command = MakeTrajectory(joint_name="upper_joint")
```

3. Сreate a system which will act as a source of the required position for joints at points in time.

```
class TrajectoriesToPosition(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self, traj_JT1, traj_JT2):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)

        self.traj_JT1_command = traj_JT1
        self.traj_JT2_command = traj_JT2

        # Becauce this system is source, we need to define output port, whose output positions 
        # will be desired positions for joints.
        # The size of port are joints*2 because I use PID controller (it has position and velocity for each input)
        # But I set here only positions
        self.DeclareVectorOutputPort(
            "joint_angles", num_of_actuated_joints*2, self.CalcPositionOutput
        )

    def CalcPositionOutput(self, context, output):
        t = context.get_time()
        JT1 = self.traj_JT1_command.value(t)[0, 0]
        JT2 = self.traj_JT2_command.value(t)[0, 0]

        output.SetFromVector(np.array([JT1, JT2, 0, 0]))
```

4. Main program

```
meshcat = StartMeshcat() # Creating visualiser

# Define the coefficients of PID controller
Kp = np.ones(num_of_actuated_joints) * 4000.0
Ki = np.ones(num_of_actuated_joints) * 1
Kd = np.ones(num_of_actuated_joints) * 400

builder = DiagramBuilder()
# Scene graph determines the position of bodies relative to each other
scene_graph = builder.AddSystem(SceneGraph())
scene_graph.set_name("scene_graph")

# As I understand, Multibody plant is a physics engine of drake-simulator
dp = builder.AddSystem(MultibodyPlant(sim_step))
dp.set_name("dp_plant")
dp.RegisterAsSourceForSceneGraph(scene_graph)

parser = Parser(dp)
# Add double pendulum in scene
dp_model_instance_index = parser.AddModelsFromString(dp_sdf, "sdf")[0]

# Adding some objects in scene
parser.SetAutoRenaming(True) # This need because I add some identical objects in scene
objects_instance = []
objects_name = []
objects_pose = []
for i in range(num_of_objects):
    objects_instance.append(
        parser.AddModels(
            url="package://drake/manipulation/models/ycb/sdf/005_tomato_soup_can.sdf"
            )[0]
        )
    objects_name.append(
            dp.GetBodyByName("base_link_soup", objects_instance[i]
            )
        )
    # Define the positions of objects above. I decided to use random  for this goal
    objects_pose.append(
        RigidTransform(
            RollPitchYaw(
                np.asarray(
                    [random.uniform(0,180), random.uniform(0,180), random.uniform(0,180)]) * np.pi / 180),
            p=[random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2), random.uniform(-0.2, 0.2), 0.3+random.uniform(-0.05, 0.05)])
        )

# This frame is double-pendulum static base and this frame is defined in sdf-decription of DP above
root_frame = dp.GetFrameByName("base")

# Determining the position of the fixed base of the DP relative to the world coordinate system
X_0 = RigidTransform(
            RollPitchYaw(
                np.array([0, 0, 0]) * np.pi / 180),
                    p=[[0], [0], [0]]
)

# Add a frame that will be associated with the world coordinate system, but will be of type FixedOffsetFrame
# I tried to weld DP base and dp.world_frame() directly, but it didn't work
world_frame_joint = dp.AddFrame(
        FixedOffsetFrame(
            "world_joint_frame", dp.world_frame(),
            X_0
        )
)

# Weld the DP base to the world coordinate system.
dp.AddJoint(
    WeldJoint(
        name="weld_base", 
        frame_on_parent_F=world_frame_joint, 
        frame_on_child_M=root_frame, 
        X_FM=X_0
    )
)

# Add actuators to joints
# Interesting points: if firstly define actuator for lower_joint in didn't work. Why??
dp.AddJointActuator("JT2", dp.GetJointByName("upper_joint"))
dp.AddJointActuator("JT1", dp.GetJointByName("lower_joint"))

# Because all of objects and joints are added, we can finalize phycics engine.
dp.Finalize()

# Add PID controller for 2 joints
# 11 port (double_pendulum_with_base_state - port) - because if I connect dp.get_state_output_port it didn't work: 
# controller input port size is 4 (q1_pos, q2_pos, q1_vel, q2_vel),
# but size of dp.get_state_output_port is 4 + 7 * number of free object (7 = 3 (XYZ) + 4 (quaternion))
# Question: Is it possible to pass the port incompletely to the PID without states of free objects?
pid = builder.AddSystem(PidController(Kp, Ki, Kd))
builder.Connect(
    dp.get_output_port(11),
    pid.get_input_port_estimated_state()
)
builder.Connect(
    pid.get_output_port_control(),
    dp.get_actuation_input_port()
)

# Add system as source of desired position
desired_base_source = builder.AddSystem(
    TrajectoriesToPosition(
        traj_JT1=traj_JT1_command, traj_JT2=traj_JT2_command
    )
)
# Everything seems clear here
builder.Connect(
    desired_base_source.get_output_port(),
    pid.get_input_port_desired_state()
)
# If interesting why we connect these ports below I reccomend 
# to read https://drake.guzhaoyuan.com/ about the interatcion of scene graph and multibody plant
builder.Connect(
    dp.get_geometry_poses_output_port(), scene_graph.get_source_pose_port(dp.get_source_id())
)
builder.Connect(
    scene_graph.get_query_output_port(), dp.get_geometry_query_input_port()
)

# Set initial positions of free objects added above
for i in range(num_of_objects):
    dp.SetDefaultFreeBodyPose(objects_name[i], objects_pose[i])

MeshcatVisualizer.AddToBuilder(builder, scene_graph, meshcat)
diagram = builder.Build()

simulator = Simulator(diagram)

# Creating and getting context to set the initial positions of actuated joints
diagram_context = diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
dp_context = dp.GetMyContextFromRoot(simulator.get_mutable_context())
positions = np.ndarray(num_of_actuated_joints)
positions[0] = 0 * np.pi/180
positions[1] = 0 * np.pi/180
dp.SetPositions(dp_context, dp_model_instance_index, positions)

simulator.Initialize()
simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.)
meshcat.StartRecording(set_visualizations_while_recording=False)
simulator.AdvanceTo(sim_time)
meshcat.PublishRecording()
```

5. Visualising full diagram

```
SVG(
    pydot.graph_from_dot_data(diagram.GetGraphvizString(max_depth=1))[0].create_svg()
)
```

PS: This code is not entirely clean and of course there is something to improve and optimize. I will be glad to receive any comments and suggestions for improvement!

Answer (score 0):

By default, all objects loaded into the MultibodyPlant in Drake are subject to gravity.

To apply additional forces to the object to make the objects move, then there are two primary mechanisms:

1. you can add a joint with an actuator, then apply forces by setting non-zero forces via the MultibodyPlant's [actuator input port](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a1cc1d71e6c2e91fcd215105ae4ed01e4).
2. you can use the MultibodyPlant's [`applied_generalized_force`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#af393d5659ac9a8807671a1efc0d78a5c) or [`applied_spatial_force`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#ab2ad1faa7547d440f008cdddd32d85e8) input ports.

If I understand your goal, then I would think that you'd want to add prismatic x and y joints + actuators to your table, apply forces through the actuators to move the table, and then you can continue to drop objects onto the table and watch the interactions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But can I set a given  position of the table at a certain time without using a controller (as for the iiwa robot) and calculating the required force in joint?

Comment: Outside of the simulation loop, you can always call `plant.SetPositions(...)` and the associated methods (e.g. you can also get the joint and set it's position).  Inside the simulation loop for MultibodyPlant, since the physics engine is updating the positions, you can only set the positions through the dynamics, which requires using forces/torques. Like in the real world.

Comment: What do you mean by inside and outside of the simulation loop? Did I understand correctly that we can use plant.SetPositions(...), SetDefaultFreeBodyPose(...), SetFreeBodyPose(...) outside of the simulation loop only once before running the simulation?

Comment: Yes, the recommended workflow is to use those methods before starting the simulation, then just call `Simulator.AdvanceTo(some large number)`.  But sometimes people will also write a loop `while (time < some large number): Simulator.AdvanceTo(time + small number)`... in which case you could use those methods between calls to `AdvanceTo`.